# How can one use dictionary kwargs as callable function parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, args, keyword-argument

I am trying to learn how to use kwargs via dictionaries as function inputs. As a simple example to learn from, I am trying to make a basic (x,y) plot for which the kwargs can specify the color of the curve and some other plot specs.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## generate data
f = lambda x : np.array([xi**2 for xi in x]) # function f(x)
x = np.linspace(0, 100)
y = f(x)

## define plotting routine
def get_plot(x, y, kwargs):
    """
    This plot will take multiple kwargs when successful.
    """
    plt.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
    plt.show()
```

I first try to generate the plot using one kwarg. This works.

```
plot_dict = dict(color='red')
get_plot(x, y, plot_dict)
>> plot appears
```

I then try to generate the plot using two kwargs. This doesn't work.

```
plot_dict = dict(color='red', xlabel='this is the x-axis')
get_plot(x, y, plot_dict)
>> AttributeError: Unknown property xlabel
```

But I was under the impression that [xlabel is a kwarg](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html) because it is a callable arg like color. What is the source of my misunderstanding/mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this:

```
def get_plot(x, y, **kwargs):
    """
    This plot will take multiple kwargs when successful.
    """
    plt.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
    plt.show()
```

and call the function like this: `get_plot(x, y, **plot_dict)`.

Check [this](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/) tutorial to understand how to use `**kwargs`.

**In nutshell**, what `**kwargs` does, is explode the dictionary into pairs of `argument=value`, i.e, `kwarg1=val1, kwarg2=val2..` instead of you doing that manually.

Comment: I tried that, but I get this error: `TypeError: get_plot() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: @mikey call it like this: `get_plot(x, y, **plot_dict)`

Comment: So I put the double-splat operator `**` for a total of three times (twice in the function and once when calling) and I am now getting this error: `AttributeError: Unknown property xlabel`

Comment: @mikey that's because `xlabel` isn't one of the kwargs supported by `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`

Comment: @mikey `xlabel` is an attribute you set after the plot has been generated: `plt.xlabel('label')`. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20xlabel#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel